# e to the power x in C

Tags: c++, exponent

I am trying to find e to the power x. Please indicate what could possibly be wrong with my current implementation rather than simply suggesting new/ore efficient solutions (i could find many on the net). There seems to be a logical or run time error, debugging it doesn't show anything. Thanks in advance!

cmath library has been included, program compiles fine..stops on run

```
double find_e_power_x(int x){
     int i = 1, j = 1, count = 1, accuracy = 15;
     double xd = static_cast<double>(x); //pow takes double args
     double jd = static_cast<double>(j);
     double epx = 1.0;
     while ( count < accuracy ){
           while ( ++i && ++j) {
                 epx += ( pow(xd,jd) / fact(i) ); //static_cast
                 count++;
           }
     }
     return epx;
}
```

In response to the comments (pointing out my infinite inner loop),

**EDIT:**

```
while ( count < accuracy ){
                 epx += ( pow(xd,jd) / fact(i) ); //static_cast
                 count++;
                 i++;
                 j++;
     }
```

input =3 answer is incorrect though it does give an output as 3.15485

---

below is the **final version** works fine

i/p = 4

o/p = 54.8278

```
double find_e_power_x(int x){
     int i = 1, count = 1, accuracy = 15;
     double xd = static_cast<double>(x); //pow takes double args
     double id = static_cast<double>(i);
     double epx = 1.0;
     while ( count < accuracy ){
                 epx += ( pow(xd,id) / fact(i) ); //static_cast
                 ++count;
                 ++id;
                 ++i;
     }
     return epx;
}
```

Comment: Could you give some sample inputs and outputs and what you expect?

Comment: What error(s) do you get ?

Comment: Also, when do you expect the inner loop to end?

Comment: Yeah, in fact this program doesn't stop, it just doesn't terminate.

Comment: @shivani. if u dnt need the inner loop . [edit] your question.

Comment: Err, isn't this provided by the `exp()` function in `cmath`?

Comment: @paxdiablo. Maybe she is just practising something. Using `pow` etc

Comment: You can check this question, and its first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827706/calculating-ex-without-using-any-functions

Comment: Ironically, `pow` might well be calling `exp` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are incrementing `j` each time round your loop, but not `jd`. Therefore your expression:

```
epx += ( pow(xd,jd) / fact(i) ); //static_cast
```

is effectively:

```
epx += ( pow(xd, 1.0) / fact(i) ); //static_cast
```

each time.

Move this line:

```
double jd = static_cast<double>(j);
```

inside your loop or just increment `jd` directly.

Comment: yeah thanks, just saw your reply post my edit. got it right already.thanks loads anyway.